# How to defer the loading of a link href image?

Tags: javascript, html

I have some links like those shown below.  You click the small image and the big image appears. How can I get all the small images to be visible when the page loads, but not load any of the large images until the link for that image is clicked, or until everything else on the page has loaded?

```
<a href='big_image_1.jpg'><img src='small_image_1.jpg' ></a>"
<a href='big_image_2.jpg'><img src='small_image_2.jpg' ></a>"
<a href='big_image_3.jpg'><img src='small_image_3.jpg' ></a>"
```

Thanks

Comment: The behavior you're asking is exactly the behavior that markup produces. The small images will be shown. The large ones won't be downloaded until the user clicks the link, which will leave the current page and start loading the large image. Can you clarify what you're asking?

Comment: You meant something like this?http://jsbin.com/rezamunuxizi/1/

Comment: I meant exactly what you understood. Thanks for the answer.